# Problem with grayscale image

Tags: matlab, grayscale

When I try to show a grayscale image using :

```
Img = imread('tr2.png');

subplot(111);

imshow(Img);
```

it does not appear as the original image. Where is the problem ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "It does not appear as the original image"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to read colormap together with the image:

```
[Img, map] = imread('tr2.png');
imshow(Img,map);
```

EDIT:

I believe you have indexed image and you have to convert it to RGB before any processing.
Use [ind2rgb](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ind2rgb.html) or [ind2gray](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/ind2gray.html) function.

See for example [Steve's blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/02/03/all-about-pixel-colors-part-2/) on indexed images.

Comment: It's work perfecty when I do it without any processing

[Img, map] = imread('tr2.png');

imshow(Img,map);

But when I add this : 

ImgFinal = Img - ImgX

subplot(212);

imshow(ImgFinal)

Comment: Please add to your question what are you trying to do. I think your comment went unfinished.

Comment: This is the final code :

[Img, map] = imread('tr2.png');

imshow(Img,map);

if isempty(map) && size(Img,3) == 3


   Img = rgb2gray(Img);                 


elseif ~isempty(map)


    Img = ind2gray(Img,map);           


end

Answer (score 2):

code to get the grayscale:

```
Img = imread('tr2.png');
gray=rgb2gray(Img);
imshow(gray);
```

(Matlab)